# Rendering ePub in two page mode

Tags: ipad, pagination, epub

I am using AePubreader sample code for reading ePub in my app. The issue I am facing is that the last page of the chapters are not rendered properly and they go off the visible area. I had edited AePubreader code in following way to convert in a two page mode in ipad.

-In chaper.m file the webViewDiDFinishLoading has following code :

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView{
    NSString *varMySheet = @"var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];";


    NSString *addCSSRule =  @"function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
    "if (mySheet.addRule) {"
        "mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);"                               // For Internet Explorer
    "} else {"
        "ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
        "mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"   // For Firefox, Chrome, etc.
    "}"
    "}";


NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; height: %fpx;-webkit-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; ')", webView.frame.size.height];    

    NSString *insertRule2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('p', 'text-align: justify;')"];
    NSString *setTextSizeRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', '-webkit-text-size-adjust: %d%%;')",fontPercentSize];

    NSString *setImageRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('img', 'max-width: %fpx; height:%fpx;')", webView.frame.size.width-200,webView.frame.size.height-200];


    NSString *setFontRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', 'font-family: Arial;' , 'font-name: Arial-BoldItalicMT;')"];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setFontRule];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setImageRule];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:varMySheet];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:addCSSRule];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule2];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setTextSizeRule];

    float totalWidth = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.body.scrollWidth"] floatValue];
    pageCount = (ceilf)((float)totalWidth/webView.frame.size.width);

    NSLog(@"Chapter %d: %@ -> %d pages & totalWidth :: %f", chapterIndex, title, pageCount,totalWidth);

    [webView dealloc];
    [delegate chapterDidFinishLoad:self];

}
```

In EpubViewController.m webViewDidFinishLoading is as follows:-

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView{

    NSString *varMySheet = @"var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];";

    NSString *addCSSRule =  @"function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
    "if (mySheet.addRule) {"
    "mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);"                               // For Internet Explorer
    "} else {"
    "ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
    "mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"   // For Firefox, Chrome, etc.
    "}"
    "}";



NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding-left: 0px;padding-right: 0px; padding-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; height: %fpx;-webkit-column-count: 2; -webkit-column-gap: 0px; ')", webView.frame.size.height];    


    NSString *insertRule2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('p', 'text-align: justify;')"];
    NSString *setTextSizeRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', '-webkit-text-size-adjust: %d%%;')", currentTextSize];
    NSString *setHighlightColorRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('highlight', 'background-color: yellow;')"];

    NSString *setImageRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('img', 'max-width: %fpx; height:%fpx;')", (webView.frame.size.width/2)-200,webView.frame.size.height-150];

    NSString *setFontRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', 'font-family: Arial;' , 'font-name: Arial-BoldItalicMT;')"];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setFontRule];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setImageRule];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:varMySheet];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:addCSSRule];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule2];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setTextSizeRule];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setHighlightColorRule];

    if(currentSearchResult!=nil){
    //  NSLog(@"Highlighting %@", currentSearchResult.originatingQuery);
        [webView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:currentSearchResult.originatingQuery];
    }

//  int totalWidth = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollWidth"] intValue];

//    NSLog(@">>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>>total width is %d",totalWidth);
//    CGFloat moduloResult = (float)(totalWidth/((int)webView.bounds.size.width % 2));

  //NSLog(@"moduloresult is %f",moduloResult);

//  pagesInCurrentSpineCount = (round)((float)totalWidth/(webView.frame.size.width));
    float pageCountofChapter = [[loadedEpub.spineArray objectAtIndex:currentSpineIndex] pageCount];
    pagesInCurrentSpineCount =(ceilf)(pageCountofChapter/2.0);

    UIScrollView* sv = nil;
    for (UIView* v in  webView.subviews) {
        if([v isKindOfClass:[UIScrollView class]])
        {
            sv = (UIScrollView*) v;
            sv.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesInCurrentSpineCount*1024, sv.contentSize.height);
        }
    }

//    NSLog(@"TotalWidth :: %d && pagesInCurrentSpineCount :: %d  && currentPageInSpineIndex :: %d",totalWidth,pagesInCurrentSpineCount,currentPageInSpineIndex);

    [self gotoPageInCurrentSpine:currentPageInSpineIndex];
}
```

I have noticed that when the pages calculated are in odd numbers the last page of the chapter is not rendered properly ? Also , is there any alternative library available which provides two page mode support to accurately render epub?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@dineshprasanna do following changes in your project.

in chapter.m file

```
- (void) webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView*)webView{
    NSString *varMySheet = @"var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];";


    NSString *addCSSRule =  @"function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
    "if (mySheet.addRule) {"
        "mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);"                               // For Internet Explorer
    "} else {"
        "ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
        "mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"   // For Firefox, Chrome, etc.
    "}"
    "}";

//  NSLog(@"w:%f h:%f", webView.bounds.size.width, webView.bounds.size.height);



   NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding-left: 50px;padding-right: 50px; padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px; -webkit-column-gap: 100px;height: %fpx; -webkit-column-width : %fpx')", webView.frame.size.height-100,webView.frame.size.width/2-200];    

    NSString *insertRule2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('p', 'text-align: justify;')"];
    NSString *setTextSizeRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', '-webkit-text-size-adjust: %d%%;')",fontPercentSize];

//    NSString *setImageRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('img', 'max-width: %fpx; height:auto;')", webView.frame.size.width *0.75];
    NSString *setImageRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('img', 'max-width: %fpx; height:%fpx;')", webView.frame.size.width/2-200,webView.frame.size.height-200];


    NSString *setFontRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', 'font-family: Arial;' , 'font-name: Arial-BoldItalicMT;')"];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setFontRule];
    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setImageRule];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:varMySheet];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:addCSSRule];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule2];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setTextSizeRule];

    int totalWidth = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollWidth"] floatValue];
    pageCount = (ceilf)((float)totalWidth/webView.frame.size.width);

    if (totalWidth % (int)webView.frame.size.width != 0)
    {
        UIScrollView *scrollV = [self getScrollViewFromWebView:webView];
        scrollV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pageCount*(webView.frame.size.width), webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);

    }


    NSLog(@"Chapter %d: %@ -> %d pages & totalWidth :: %d", chapterIndex, title, pageCount,totalWidth);

    [activityIndicator removeFromSuperview];
    [activityIndicator stopAnimating];
    [webView dealloc];


    [delegate chapterDidFinishLoad:self];

}
```

in your epubviewcontroller file :-

```
- (void)webViewDidFinishLoad:(UIWebView *)theWebView{

    NSString *varMySheet = @"var mySheet = document.styleSheets[0];";

    NSString *addCSSRule =  @"function addCSSRule(selector, newRule) {"
    "if (mySheet.addRule) {"
    "mySheet.addRule(selector, newRule);"                               // For Internet Explorer
    "} else {"
    "ruleIndex = mySheet.cssRules.length;"
    "mySheet.insertRule(selector + '{' + newRule + ';}', ruleIndex);"   // For Firefox, Chrome, etc.
    "}"
    "}";



//    NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'PADDING-LEFT: 25px; padding-top: 100px; padding-right: 25px; height: %fpx; -webkit-column-gap: 50px; -webkit-column-width:%fpx;')", webView.frame.size.height-200, (webView.frame.size.width/2-100) ];

    NSString *insertRule1 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('html', 'padding-left: 50px;padding-right: 50px; padding-top: 50px; padding-bottom: 50px; -webkit-column-gap: 100px;height: %fpx; -webkit-column-width : %fpx')", webView.frame.size.height-100,webView.frame.size.width/2-200];     


    NSString *insertRule2 = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('p', 'text-align: justify;')"];
    NSString *setTextSizeRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', '-webkit-text-size-adjust: %d%%;')", currentTextSize];
    NSString *setHighlightColorRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('highlight', 'background-color: yellow;')"];

    NSString *setImageRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('img', 'max-width: %fpx; height:%fpx;')", (webView.frame.size.width/2)-200,webView.frame.size.height-200];

    NSString *setFontRule = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"addCSSRule('body', 'font-family: Arial;' , 'font-name: Arial-BoldItalicMT;')"];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setFontRule];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setImageRule];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:varMySheet];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:addCSSRule];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule1];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:insertRule2];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setTextSizeRule];

    [webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:setHighlightColorRule];

    if(currentSearchResult!=nil){
    //  NSLog(@"Highlighting %@", currentSearchResult.originatingQuery);
        [webView highlightAllOccurencesOfString:currentSearchResult.originatingQuery];
    }


    float pageCountofChapter = [[loadedEpub.spineArray objectAtIndex:currentSpineIndex] pageCount];
    pagesInCurrentSpineCount =pageCountofChapter;

    int totalWidth = [[webView stringByEvaluatingJavaScriptFromString:@"document.documentElement.scrollWidth"] floatValue];

    if (totalWidth % (int)webView.frame.size.width != 0)
    {
        UIScrollView *scrollV = [self getScrollViewFromWebView:webView];
        scrollV.contentSize = CGSizeMake(pagesInCurrentSpineCount*(webView.frame.size.width), webView.scrollView.contentSize.height);

    }

    [self gotoPageInCurrentSpine:currentPageInSpineIndex];
}
```

Hope this will help you. Arrange the padding and margin as per your requirement.

Comment: Thanks sir,But whats the action performing in this method UIScrollView *scrollV = [self getScrollViewFromWebView:webView];

Answer (score 1):

I had changed the logic by providing column numbers and managed contentsize for the scrollview of webview when it is not in the multiple of page width. Thanks for your time

Comment: Hi,Here i am also using the Aepubreader and i am also totalyy confused by landscape mode could you help me,how can i implement the landscape mode